# Prevent docker-machine from downloading newer boot2docker iso?

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

Is there some way to prevent docker-machine from trying to download a newer boot2docker image iso when running `docker-machine create` ?

Note I already have an image in my `~/.docker/machine/cache` directory that works fine - `docker-machine` is just trying to grab a newer one.

Note 2:  turning off my computer's wifi works, but that's far from optimal.